# Увеличение и перемещени изображения Android

Tags: android, изображения, imageview, drag-n-drop

Добрый день! Подскажите как увеличить изображение установленное в imageView щипком и добавить возможность последующего его перемещения?

Сейчас увеличиваю данным способом:

```
@Override
public boolean onDoubleTap(MotionEvent e) {
    if (!isImageScaled) mImageViev.animate().scaleX(1.4f).scaleY(1.4f).setDuration(500);
    if (isImageScaled) mImageViev.animate().scaleX(1f).scaleY(1f).setDuration(500);
    isImageScaled = !isImageScaled;
    return false;
}
```

По перемещению вообще ничего не понимаю. Drag and Drop не выходит у меня

Comment: Можно использовать https://github.com/chrisbanes/PhotoView вместо стандартного ImageView. В PhotoView поддерживается увеличение

Comment: @ValeryPonomarenko , а перемещать тоже умеет?

Comment: Перемещать после того, как изображение было приближено? Если так, то умеет